# Beanshell script over all testng suites

Tags: xml, testng, beanshell

I have 30+ xml test suites for various configurations.
Recently I introduced beanshell script to handle dynamic group management.
This required me to modify each xml to include code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" > <suite name="testSuite" parallel="none" >
    <test name="website general suite">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell">
                    <![CDATA[whatGroup = System.getProperty("groupToRun","");
                        if(whatGroup.isEmpty()){
                          return true;
                        }
                        else{
                          return groups.containsKey(whatGroup) ;
                        }
                ]]>
                </script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.autoqa.website.tests.ExperiencePagesTests"/>
            <class name="com.autoqa.website.tests.FooterTests"/>
            <class name="com.autoqa.website.tests.HeroSliderTests"/>
            <class name="com.autoqa.website.tests.PosterTests"/>
            <class name="com.autoqa.website.tests.SimpleSmokeTests"/>
            <class name="com.autoqa.website.tests.WhatsOnTests"/>
            <class name="com.autoqa.website.tests.UTagJSTests"/>
            <class name="com.autoqa.website.tests.UTagsProxyTests"/>
        </classes>
    </test> </suite>
```

As it works, I wonder if there is a way to have this script in just one place and to inject it to each xml in simple way. So, say, if in future I would like to modify this script I would do it just once instead of inside 30+ xmls.

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting this done is by doing the following :

1. Ensure you are using latest released version of TestNG viz., `6.13.1`
2. Build a TestNG listener that implements `org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener`
3. Wire in this listener via the `<listeners>` tag in your suite xml file.
4. If you would want, you can enrich this listener by adding conditions such that it adds up the beanshell script based on some specific condition.

Following is a full fledged example that shows all of this in action.

**Sample test class**

```java
package com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn48205890;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleTestClass {
    @Test
    public void a() {}

    @Test
    public void b() {}

    @Test
    public void c() {}
}
```

The TestNG listener that implements `org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener`

```java
package com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn48205890;

import org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener;
import org.testng.xml.XmlMethodSelector;
import org.testng.xml.XmlScript;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class BeanShellScriptInjector implements IAlterSuiteListener {
    @Override
    public void alter(List<XmlSuite> suites) {
        XmlSuite suite = suites.get(0);
        XmlMethodSelector xms = new XmlMethodSelector();
        XmlScript script = new XmlScript();
        script.setLanguage("beanshell");
        script.setScript("System.out.println(\"Running \" + method.getName() + \"()\") ; return true;");
        xms.setScript(script);
        List<XmlMethodSelector> list = Collections.singletonList(xms);
        XmlTest xmlTest = suite.getTests().get(0);
        xmlTest.setMethodSelectors(list);
    }
}
```

**TestNG suite xml file**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="45160355_Suite" parallel="false" verbose="2">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn48205890.BeanShellScriptInjector"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="45160355_test" verbose="2">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn48205890.SampleTestClass"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Console output**

```
...
... TestNG 6.13.1 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...

Running a()
Running b()
Running c()
Running a()
Running b()
Running c()
Running a()
Running b()
Running c()PASSED: a
PASSED: b
PASSED: c

===============================================
    45160355_test
    Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

===============================================
45160355_Suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```